# How to get event observer data after save category?

Tags: magento-1.8, event-observer, category

I want to export data of a category when its save in magento system. So, I also create a module & create a event name which is **catalog_category_save_commit_after**.
My code is like below..

```
<config>
<global>
 ....
<events>
        <catalog_category_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <category_category_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Feed_Category_Model_Category_Observer</class>
                    <method>saveCategoryData</method>
                </category_category_observer>
            </observers>
        </catalog_category_save_commit_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

```
class Feed_Category_Model_Category_Observer
{
    public function saveCategoryData($observer)
    {              

        $category = $observer->getEvent()->getDataObject();
        Mage::log($category);
        // or
        Mage::log($observer->getEvent()->getCategory());    

    }
 }
```

Both are return blank. Have any idea??

Comment: The code looks ok. Are you sure that the log is turned on? To be sure that something is logged, do it this way. `Mage::log('what to log', null, 'system.log', true);`

Comment: @Marius, can you explain what is the purpose of **NULL** in your statement?

Comment: That's the level for logging. If it's set to null it defaults to `Zend_Log::DEBUG`. Look in the `Mage::log` method for more details

Comment: add magento log like `Mage::log($category, null, 'observer_category_data.log');` . It's work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used this in `sales_order_place_after` event

```
public function myMethod(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $data = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        Mage::log($data , null, 'sales_order_place_data.log');   
}
```

Maybe it will be helps you.

You can try this

> ```
> $data = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory();
> Mage::log($data , null, 'sales_order_place_data.log');
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your response. but this is not a acceptable answer. I also used **$data = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory();**.

Comment: **Mage::log($data->debug());** Try this to print an object in log file.

Comment: @Supravat please try this `Mage::log($data , null, 'observer_category_data.log'); `

Answer (score 2):

To see what kind of data is available the fastest way is to check where the `dispachtEvent` is called. This [cheatsheet](http://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-7/) should help you with that.

If you open the class on line 334 you can see what data is passed. Looking at the code it should be something like this:

```
var_dump($observer->getDataObject()->getData());
```